# Unicode (Hebrew) typing: Works in some applications but not others

Tags: gnome-terminal, encoding, unicode, hebrew

Recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 (Kubuntu, incidentally; but I experience this issue with both gnome-terminal and Konsole).

I have Hebrew selected as a language and as an input method.

When I try to type Hebrew in the terminal, if I'm in bash prompt, nothing shows up. Some of the letters appear bound to actions (e.g. delete the current line. I don't expect unicode to do such stuff).
But in the same terminal, if I'm in `cat` (i.e. just typing without having the shell intercept my keystrokes), the letters show up fine.

Also: In Firefox and Pidgin Hebrew works fine. In Chromium - can't type Hebrew.

Using xxd I see that my input is understood by the terminal to be unicode, which is as I expect.

What might be the problem? Am I supposed to tell bash or the terminal what my encoding is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the problem was incorrect setting of my locale. My locale was set to `en_IL.UTF-8`, which apparently isn't recognized/supported. I changed all entries in `/etc/default/locales` to be `en_US.UTF-8`, and then **logged out and logged in again** - now I can type in Hebrew where previously I couldn't.